# Discord Bot doesn't behave same in different servers

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I have made a Discord bot using javascript (I'm very new to js) and once I add it to two different discord servers, even though it has the same permissions, it doesn't work the same way.
The bot should post a message every monday at 9am to a specific channel named "design-challenges". In one server it does exactly that, in the other server it doesn't. The bot is online in both servers and I can see it runs basic commands like !hello fine in both.

Here's my code, if that helps:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const cron = require('node-cron');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
});

const prefix = '!';
const challengeChannelName = 'design-challenges';
let challenges;

// Store the current challenge index
let currentChallengeIndex = 1;

client.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
  challenges = await loadChallenges();
  scheduleWeeklyChallenge();
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    // Ignore messages from bots
    if (message.author.bot) return;
  
    // Check if the message starts with the command prefix
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
      const [command, ...args] = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
  
      if (command === 'ping') {
        message.channel.send('Pong!');
      } else if (command === 'hello') {
        message.channel.send('Hello!');
      }
      if(command === 'challenge') {
        const challenge = getNextChallenge();
        message.channel.send(challenge);
      }
    }
  });
  

function scheduleWeeklyChallenge() {
  // Set a cron job to send a challenge every Monday at 9:00 AM
  cron.schedule('0 8 * * 1', () => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === challengeChannelName);

    if (channel) {
      const introText = `
@everyone
# Er du klar til at udfordre dine designfærdigheder?
Vi inviterer dig til at deltage i vores seneste udfordring og give dine medstuderende feedback.\nHusk at upload din challenge lige herunder, ikke som reply.

Denne uges challenge er:`;
      const challenge = getNextChallenge();

      // Send introductory message
      channel.send(introText)
        .then(() => {
          // Wait for a moment (you can adjust the timeout duration) before sending the challenge
          return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
        })
        .then(() => {
          // Send the challenge
          channel.send(challenge);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error sending challenge:', error));
    }
  });
}

async function loadChallenges() {
  try {
    const data = await fs.readFile('challenges.json');
    return JSON.parse(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error loading challenges:', error);
    return [];
  }
}

function getNextChallenge() {
  const currentIndex = currentChallengeIndex;
  const nextChallenge = challenges[currentIndex];

  // Increment the challenge index for the next time
  currentChallengeIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % challenges.length;

  return `## ${currentIndex + 1}: ${nextChallenge.title}
* **What**: ${nextChallenge.what}
* **Target**: ${nextChallenge.target}
`;
}

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.channel.name === 'design-challenges' && message.attachments.size > 0) {
      const thread = await message.channel.threads.create({
          name: `feedback-${message.author.displayName}`,
      });

      await thread.send(`${message.author} har indgivet et bidrag. Giv jeres konstruktive feedback herunder.`);
      await thread.send(`Oprindelig fil: ${message.attachments.first().url}`);
  }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I don't understand why it works in one server but it doesn't work in the other. Please help